# Can't make request to API on React-Native app when Debug JS Remotely is enabled

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, cross-domain

I currently work on a React-Native mobile app.

The requests to the server API using `fetch` works fine, but when I open the "Debug JS Remotely" with Google Chrome, it creates some kind of localhost server and the calls are made from it, and I get the following error from the server API:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my.server.com/data. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.

It's pretty annoying not to be able to track the requests to the server in debug mode.

Any of you have faced a similar issue and do you have a way around it?

Thanks

Comment: any specific solution to this problem , I am still facing issue with ios only ,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually found a solution: I installed the Chrome extension `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:*`
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: apart from adding extension , do i need to configure some setting

Answer (score 0):

For react-native change your debug url in chrome  http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ with http://192.168.xxx.xx.xip.io:8081/debugger-ui/

Ex: http://192.168.10.112.xx.xip.io:8081/debugger-ui/

**OR**

Add

```
mres.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

to

```
/node_modules/metro/src/Server\index.js
```